# How to remove directories that have numbers as file names in Ubuntu using command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I have a directory where there are subdirectories which have numbers as directories. For example I have a parent directory `test` now I have some subdirectories like `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`. Now I have a local exported variable like `export a=3`. I want to delete directories that are `above or equal to $a` and `below or equal to $a+3`, So I want to delete files `4`,`5`. How can I achieve this in `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS`.

I tried `rm -rf {$a..$($a+3)}`, it didn't work, I tried so many other things but not successful.

Comment: Really has nothing to do with the OS. The question is how to do this in a script or the command line.

Comment: @David where would be the right place to post this? Could you please suggest?

Comment: It is fine to be here just being clear it is not an OS issue. The command or script would be the same on an Linux.

Comment: @David You could say that about almost any question on here. If they are using Ubuntu, it should be on topic.

Comment: Please include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Thanks.

Comment: @mchid added the Ubuntu version that I am using.

Comment: You are likely to have better luck asking this question in a more general place, as it is not a question about Ubuntu. try: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can only use integer or single characters inside a sequence expression, brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, there will not be any interpretation of the text between the braces, and incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged. You can do `eval rm {$a..$((a+2))}`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
rm -r $(seq $a $((a+3)))
```

(Provided you really meant what you illustrated with your code sample, ie. directories above *or equal to* `$a` and below *or equal to* `$a+3`, instead of what you wrote in the text, "above `>$3` but below `<$3+2`".

Comment: It worked, Thanks for the answer. I will edit the question.

Comment: How to remove everthing that is below or equal to `$a-1` but don't know the least number with a directory?

Comment: Simply `rm -rf $(seq 1 $((a-1)))`. It will delete the existing directories, and the `-f` option will suppress the error messages about the non-existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following method to remove folders or files.

1. Send the output of the respective folder to a text file `ls >> text.txt`
2. Edit the text.txt file to remove all those entries which you don't want to remove.
3. issue the command `sudo rm -r -i $(cat text.txt)`.
   Use `-i` flag if you want the process to be interactive.
4. When removing files, do not use `-r`  flag.

This method would work where the folders that you wish to remove are not in consecutive order.

Comment: This is where I get goose bumps. Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Thanks I don't think I have the skill set to fully understand the intricacies/issues with ```ls``` command as explained in the post. Frankly speaking I have not seen such complicated filename or directory names.